# Dynamical assignment of values in Delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti

I am creating a control similar to object inspector , So i want to assign any changes to the property to the relevant object.

```
var

v:TValue ;
 ctx : TRttiContext;
begin

  //  k.IsOrdinal := true ;
v := v.FromVariant(2)  ;


ctx.GetType(tButton).GetProperty('Style').SetValue(Button1, v.AsOrdinal);

end;
```

above is my code , but i am getting invalid type cast error.

Is it possible to handle any variable and enums .(No need of objects and records as it is very complicated )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to SetValue needs to read like this:

```
SetValue(Button1, TValue.From(TButton.TButtonStyle(2)))
```

In your code, the use of `AsOrdinal` is incorrect. That is a function that returns a `TRttiOrdinalType`. But `TRttiOrdinalType` is [described thus](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/RTTI.TRttiOrdinalType):

> TRttiOrdinalType is the class used to describe all the Delphi ordinal value types, such as Integer, Byte, Word, and so on.

But you need to provide a `TValue` that represents a `TButtonStyle`, which is what the code above achieves.

---

As an aside, I initially tried to use the generic [`TValue.From<T>()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TValue.From) function like this:

```
SetValue(Button1, TValue.From<TButton.TButtonStyle>(TButton.TButtonStyle(2)));
```

But that just resulted in the following internal compiler error:

> [DCC Fatal Error] Unit58.pas(38): F2084 Internal Error: URW1147

[QC#103129](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=103129)

Every time I attempt to use generics I end up being defeated by these internal errors!

Thanks to Serg for pointing out the alternative form of calling the [parameterised method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Generics#Parameterized_Methods) using type inference does not fall foul of the internal error.

Comment: I guess you misuse generics here; try just `SetValue(Button1, TValue.From(TButton.TButtonStyle(2)));`

Comment: @Serg You are correct that the form you give, which uses type inference, does not result in an internal error. But I'm not misusing generics here. The syntax I used is perfectly valid: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Generics#Parameterized_Methods

Comment: @DavidHeffernan When I try to use generics I just try every meaningful syntax, and do not look into docs. Usually something works. :)